# find common parent using Xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I was wondering if there was any way to access common parent node using Xpath.

```
<outer>
<main>
           <a><b> sometext </b></a>
           <c><d> sometext2 </d></c>
</main>
</outer>
```

I have the text nodes sometext and sometext2. is there a way i can access main (common parent) of these two nodes? I do not know the layout of the xml containing these nodes.

Answer (score 16):

**Use the following XPath 1.0 expression**:

```
$v1/ancestor::*
   [count(. | $v2/ancestor::*) 
   = 
    count($v2/ancestor::*)
   ]
    [1]
```

**where $v1 and $v2 hold the two text nodes** (in case you use XPath not within XSLT, you will have to replace $v1 and $v2 in the above expression with the XPath expressions that select each one of these two text nodes).

**Explanation**:

**The above XPath 1.0 expression finds the intersection of two node-sets**: the node-set of all element ancestors of $v1 and the node-set of all element ancestors of $v2. **This is done with the so called Kaysian method for intersection** (after Michael Kay, who discovered this in 2000). Using the Kaysian method for intersection, **the intersection of two nodesets, $ns1 and $ns2 is selected by the following XPath expression**:

```
  $ns1[count(. | $ns2) = count($ns2)]
```

**Then, from the intersection of the ancestors we must select the last element**. However, **because we are using a reverse axis (ancestor), the required node position must be denoted as 1**.

**One can quickly verify that the above XPath expression really selects the lowest common ancestor**, by applying the following transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:variable name="v1" select="/*/*/a/b/text()"/>
  <xsl:variable name="v2" select="/*/*/c/d/text()"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vCommonAncestor" select=
   "$v1/ancestor::*
       [count(. | $v2/ancestor::*) 
       = 
        count($v2/ancestor::*)
       ]
        [1]"
   />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="name($vCommonAncestor)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the originally-provided XML document** (corrected to well-formed XML):

```
<outer>
    <main>
        <a>
            <b>sometext</b>
        </a>
        <c>
            <d>sometext2</d>
        </c>
    </main>
</outer>
```

**the wanted result** (the name of the element that is the lowest common ancestor of the two text nodes) **is produced**:

**main**

**The XPath 2.0 expression that selects the lowest common ancestor of the two nodes is simpler**, because it uses the standard XPath 2.0 operator "intersect":

```
   ($v1/ancestor::* intersect $v2/ancestor::*) 
                                         [last()]
```

Comment: Hi,
As a follow up to the Xpath expression you mentioned. I'm kinda new to XPath and am accessing text nodes using Node objects (java). How do I compile this expression using the two node objects I have as parameters? something like (n1/ancestor::* intersect n2/ancestor::*) .. ?

Thanks

Comment: Replace $v1 with: /*/*/a/b/text() and $v2 with: /*/*/c/d/text()

Comment: Dimitre, I love how every one of you answers that I've seen uses the same method! And I'm actually serious about that! I just used a modified version: `$v1/ancestor-or-self::*[count(. | $v2/ancestor-or-self::*) = count($v2/ancestor-or-self::*)][1]` just in case one of the nodes is the parent of the other (or they're both the same). I just wish I understood the method enough to remember it without looking it up each time!

Comment: @CJDennis, This is just a well-known set-theoretic identity, and its meaning is simple: all nodes from `$ns1` that also belong to `$ns2`

Answer (score 3):

This seems complicated. Just try:

```
xquery version "3.0";

let $test :=
    <outer>
    <main>
               <a><b> sometext </b></a>
               <c><d> sometext2 </d></c>
    </main>
    </outer>

return ($test//*[.//b][.//d])[last()]
```

to get  i.e. the clostest common ancestor