# How to get the common set of two xpath expressions

Tags: xpath

Can someone tell me please
How to get the common set of two xpath expressions. That is opposite of Union (not |)

Comment: In XPath 2.0 - you have `intersect` - prior to that there's the `Kaysian` method - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538293/find-common-parent-using-xpath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is the well-known Kayessian formula (identity) for selecting the intersection of two node-sets `$ns1` and `$ns2`** :

```
$ns1[count(. | $ns2) = count($ns2)]
```

This formula can be used in all versions of XPath, including 1.0. Just substitute `$ns1` and `$ns2` with your specific XPath expressions that select the two node-sets you want to intersect.

Comment: Thank you @Dimitre Novatchev This is interesting.

Comment: @Ravi, You are welcome. Thank you for asking such interesting question.