# Extract nodes in between specific requirements

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

I'm trying to come up with a clean Xpath 1.0 expression to return all nodes in between specific nodes. The requirements are:

- All nodes **after** the very last numeric node;
- but **before** the very first node that starts with a opening paranthesis.

To test what I'm doing you could use:

```
<t>
    <s>ABC</s>
    <s>123</s>
    <s>DEF</s>
    <s>456</s>
    <s>GHI</s>
    <s>JKL</s>
    <s>(M)</s>
    <s>NOP</s>
    <s>(Q)</s>
</t>
```

To only end up with both 'GHI'  and 'JKL' I came up with:

```
//s[position()<count(//s[starts-with(., '(')][1]/preceding::*)+1][position()>count(//s[.*0=0][last()]/preceding::*)+1]
```

It works just fine, however I can't help but feeling this can be done much smoother. To do so I though there should be a way to use the retrieved nodes in prior Xpath, e.g:

- To get all nodes after the last numeric node: `[.*0=0][last()]/following::s`.
- To get the 1st nodes that starts with a opening paranthesis: `[starts-with(., '(')][1]`.
- But I fail to combine the statements into a valid syntax as I think something along the lines of: `//s[.*0=0][last()]/following::s[position()<[starts-with(.,'(')][1]]` which obviously is incorrect.

Any ideas, or am I stuck with what I got in the first place? I'm using this in the Excel function `FILTERXML()`.

Answer (score 1):

It's very difficult to do this with xpath 1.0 (though it's very easy with xpath 2.0), but since you are using Excel and `FILTERXML()`, the following is a possible workaround:

Assuming your xml is in A1, then in B1 user `FILTERXML()` for the first set:

```
=FILTERXML(A1,"//s[translate(., translate(.,'0123456789',''), '')][last()]//following::s")
```

[Credit here goes to the "double translate" method.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7338084/9448090)

And again in the C1:

```
=FILTERXML(A1,"//s[starts-with(., '(')][1]/preceding::s")
```

Then it's back to Excel. Either:

```
=FILTER(B:B,COUNTIF(C:C,B:B))
```

or

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B:B,C:C,0)),"",B:B)
```

This should output 'GHI' and 'JKL'.

Per OP's comment below, there is also a way to do that with one xpath 1.0 expression [using the Kayessian method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16556754/9448090), which in this case would take the form of:

```
//s[translate(., translate(.,'0123456789',''), '')][last()]//following::s[count(. | //s[starts-with(., '(')][1]/preceding::s) = count(//s[starts-with(., '(')][1]/preceding::s)]
```

and, strangely enough `FILTERXML()` understands it!

Comment: Thanks for this, but I'm more interested in a single xpath expression that will return the required array of nodes in a smoother way than the long roundabout route I took. Nonetheless, cheers for the input!

Comment: Got you, see edit (though I'm not sure it necessarily qualifies as "smoother"...)