# Find common parent using RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium, xpath, rselenium

I am looking for the equivalent of [find common parent using Xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538293/find-common-parent-using-xpath) in RSelenium.

Say I have:

```
<body>
    <table>
           <tr><td> sometext </td></tr>
           <tr><td> other </td></tr>
           <tr><td> digital </td></tr>
           <tr><td> digi </td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

I would like to get the parent of (sometext, digital and digi).

My best try (didnt work out):

```
xpath <- "(//body//*[contains(text(), 'text')][contains(text(), 'digi')])[last()]"
remDr$findElements("xpath", xpath)
```

Expected output is:

```
table
```

**Clarfication:**:
I would like to find the table tag! I dont want to specify it beforehand as an input.

Comment: Can you clarify *even more*: do you need to select parent of two or more siblings with specific values? If so do you need to preserve the order of those elements?

Answer (score 1):

You can try XPath

```
//tr[td[normalize-space()="digi"]]/parent::*
```

if you want to select *grandparent* (note that `table` is not direct parent of `td`) element of cell with specific value

If you want to get `table` matched by multiple cells:

```
//*[tr[normalize-space(td)="digi"] and tr[normalize-space(td)="digital"]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The question assumes that i dont know the tag "table" beforehand. Instead i want to find it.  I made an edit to the post, see "clarfication". On the next page that is analysed, it could be similar Information, but it is wrapped within a common div tag,....

Comment: @ThanksGuys  check updated answer. Did you mean that? Note that `table` is not *parent* of `td`!

Answer (score 1):

To find the *common parent* using *Xpath* through *RSelenium* you can use the following solution:

- `XPath1`:

  ```
  //table//tr/td[normalize-space()='sometext'][normalize-space()='digital'][normalize-space()='digi']/../..
  ```
- `XPath2` (considering *you don't know the tag `<table>`*):

  ```
  //td[normalize-space()='sometext' and normalize-space()='digital' and normalize-space()='digi']//preceding::table[1]
  ```